# Positive definite order and matrix norm induced by weighted vector norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, positive-semidefinite

Let $W$ be an $n$ by $n$ nonsingular matrix that defines a weighted two norm for vectors in $\Re^n$. Define an induced matrix norm by this weighted norm. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are positive semi-definite matrices such that $A\geq B$ ($A-B$ is positive semidefinite), is it true that $\Vert A\Vert \geq \Vert B\Vert$? I know for the case where $W$ is the identity matrix, the inequality would hold, but cannot show the inequality for the weighted case.

Comment: what happens when $n=2?$

Comment: I’ll try to think about an counter example in this case.

Comment: When you say $A\ge B$, do you mean this to be elementwise, or in the sense that $A-B$ is a positive semidefinite matrix?

Comment: I mean that the difference is a positive semi definite matrix.

Comment: @lychtalent What exactly is the weighted norm associated with $W$ in this case? Is it $\|x\|_W = \|Wx\|_2$? Or, is it $\|x\|_W = x^TWx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $\|x\|_W = \|Wx\|_2$. The induced norm can be described as
$$
\|A\| = \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_W}{\|x\|_W} = \max_{x \neq 0}\frac{\|WAx\|_2}{\|Wx\|_2} = \max_{y \neq 0} \frac{\|WAW^{-1}y\|_2}{\|y\|_2} = \|WAW^{-1}\|_2.
$$
With that in mind, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{3&0\\0&3}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}, \quad  W_t = \pmatrix{t&0\\0&1}.
$$
Note that $A \geq B$ (and indeed, $A > B$). On the other hand, note that for any matrix $M$, $\|M\|_2 \geq |m_{ij}|$ for all entries $m_{ij}$ of $M$. Thus, we find that the matrix
$$
M = W_tBW_t^{-1} = \pmatrix{1 & t\\t^{-1} & 1}
$$
satisfies $\|M\| \geq t$ for $t > 0$. Thus, with $t = 4$ for example, we find that
$$
\|A\|_{W_t} = \|W_tAW_t^{-1}\|_2 = \|A\|_2 = 3 < t \leq \|B\|_{W_t}.
$$

Comment: Great example! Thanks!